# Unable to find a region via the region provider chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am getting SdkClientException while creating a pipeline for Elastic Transcoder.Someone please help!

public void createPipeLine() {

```
    AmazonElasticTranscoderClient client=new AmazonElasticTranscoderClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));

    //create Role 
    AmazonIdentityManagement c=AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard().build();
    c.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));

    CreateRoleRequest req= new  CreateRoleRequest().withPath("/")
                                                    .withRoleName("myRole")
                                                    .withAssumeRolePolicyDocument("");
    CreateRoleResult res=c.createRole(req);

    //create Pipeline
    CreatePipelineRequest request= new CreatePipelineRequest();
    request.setInputBucket("1234videoabcd");
    request.setOutputBucket("16videoabc");
    request.setRole("req");
    request.setName("pipeline123");

    CreatePipelineResult result=client.createPipeline(request);

}
```

Comment: what is the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

add withRegion

```
AmazonIdentityManagementc =AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder
.standard()
.withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1))
.build();
```